# how to generate for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, user-input

Hello had a pretty simple problem, I'm trying to create a console program in C# that gets 3 inputs from the user. The start, stop and number of steps.

It's supposed to be a for loop but I don't really get how I can put user input in the for loop, I tried making int's of the user input and then placing the names of the int's in the for loop but it's giving me errors.

The program is supposed to look like the following program in "Ovning 1" site is in Swedish but I hope you guys will get it, tried searching the site but there was never an explanation given. http://csharpskolan.se/showarticle.php?id=119

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ovning12
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Start");
        int startNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Stop");
        int stopNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Steg");
        int stegNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (int startNummer; startNummer >= stopNummer; startNummer + stegNummer) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine();


        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In your for loop you have a write an empty line.. you could ask for input - and then do something with it - what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean empty line? Is not the Console.WriteLine(); supposed to spit out the numbers? I tried Console.WriteLine(startNummer); still errors tho. My thinking it had something to do with the int's not being connected somehow to the for loop since its static void but I'm not that experienced yet with those.

Comment: Why would it? you said "Console.WriteLine();" which just writes out a line feed.. so if you had 200 lines you would get 200 line feeds.  If you want it to print something you need to tell it what.

Comment: What are you expecting to print? The number of loops that iterates based on user input?

Comment: A few problems here, first, you already declared startNummer above the loop, don't declare it again in the for loop declaration, use an index variable instead, such as `currentNummer`. Also, it should be `currentNummer <= stopNummer` instead of `currentNummer >= stopNummer` as you are indicating the condition on which the for loop will continue until the condition is no longer true (assuming that the stopNummer should be greater than the startNummer). Also, it's good practice to validate the values entered, so perhaps display an error if `startNummer > stopNummer`

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm stupid. A bit tired have been studying all day. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FredomTrucer it's not being stupid. It's called learning. We've all been there. And trust me, we'd be the pot calling the kettle black for knocking someone for syntax mistakes, we've all done that as well. It was a good question as for loops are very difficult for new programmers to understand in terms of how to use user inputs to control them.

Comment: Now you can see fubo's or BviLLe_Kid's answer, it should give you the expected results :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Start");
        int startNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Stop");
        int stopNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Mata in Steg");
        int stegNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (int n = startNummer; n < stopNummer; n += stegNummer)
        {
            Console.Write(n + " ");
           Console.Write("{0} ", n); //(Alternative)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `n >= stopNummer`? or `n < stopNummer`?

Comment: @Pikoh good pick up.. I was just re-using OP's original post.. wasn't really paying attention to the conditions

Comment: Ok..removing my -1 :)

Comment: @Pikoh thank you haha I gave you credit for picking my error haha

Comment: It does not show the numbers just scrolls down, might be a bug on my end, but thanks! So you have to name the int even if its already named beforehand.

Comment: BviLLe, instead of `Console.WriteLine()` it should be `Console.Write(n+" ");` See the OP refered page

Comment: You only showed half of the solution, this does not actually demonstrate display the steps as indicated by the link to the Swedish page. `Console.WriteLine()` should be changed to `Console.Write(n + " ")` to match the output given by the Swedish page.

Comment: @FredomTrucer Correct, you have to initialize a start value for a for loop

Comment: @JamesH I have edited my post.. that's why I commented asking what he was trying to print.. I figured he would be able to tell all of us without having to reference another page

Comment: Ok but still not exact. The referenced page tell us de output should be something like `12 14 16 18`... so it should be `Write`, not `WriteLine` :)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yes I didn't really understand what it was looking for either until I saw the Swedish page. I can't really read Swedish, although I can read some German ;) Anyways it became obvious it was looking to print out the steps in the specified enumeration.

Comment: @Pikoh haha very true another good pick up haha just me using OP's original code again haha

Comment: @JamesH yeah i am proficient only in English haha so good thing there were pictures

Comment: @FredomTrucer - In answer to your question _So you have to name the int even if its already named beforehand_ - You could change the for loop as follows to avoid creating the extra temporary variable, but it's not recommended:  `for (; startNummer < stopNummer; startNummer += stegNummer)`

Answer (score 4):

a for loop should look like this

```
for (int i = startNummer; i <= stopNummer; i += stegNummer) 
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

there are 3 mistakes in your current code:

```
for (int startNummer; startNummer >= stopNummer; startNummer + stegNummer)
```

- you can't initialize a variable twice `int startNummer;` - that won't compile
- your comparison heads into the wrong direction (except you're working with negative steps) `startNummer >= stopNummer`
- you're not assigning the calculated new step here `startNummer + stegNummer` - it should be `startNummer += stegNummer` or  `startNummer =  startNummer + stegNummer`

Comment: This is correct, although (and this is nitpicky) but using the variable `Temp` is not good practice. Naming things is difficult, but really something that you can read and know exactly what it means is ideal. Considering the native language used, I would suggest `currentNummer` or whatever the translated version of `current` is

Comment: Well @JamesH, i usually use `i` as variable name in the for loops. Maybe is because i'm old and it used to be that way ;)

Comment: @Pikoh I do as well, but `i` is at least a common convention that most developers will understand. But `Temp` doesn't really tell me anything, where at least with `i` I know it is an index for a loop to use in with an array. Again, it's being nitpicky I know. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most of it looks okay. But couple of things do not make sense,

```
for (int startNummer; startNummer >= stopNummer; startNummer + stegNummer);
{
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

there's a semi colon ';' at the end of for loop. This ends for loop, making next curly braces syntax error. Also startNumber >= stopNumber and then startNumber + stegNumber would possibly either not run it at all, or run an infinite loop based on the inputs.

Is this for loop supposed to be like below?

```
for (int start = startNummer /*have to initialize the start value*/; 
     start < stopNummer; 
     start += stegNummer)
{
        Console.Write(start + " "); //need Console.Write to print all numbers on same line. Console.WriteLine puts each index on its own line
}
```

Comment: `startNummer + stegNummer` is incorrect. Also, as stated in other comments, startNummer has already been declared as well above the loop.

Comment: Indeed! :( Should have kept compiler in front :D

Comment: I have found that my brain is the equivalent of Fisher Price Baby's First Compiler ;)